# Cannot choose port on cloning git via ssh from aptana studio 3

Tags: git, ssh, port, aptana, aptana3

I am trying to import a git project to aptana from gitlab. In the dialog aptana shows to stUp the details for the git URI. I found out that there is no way to determine the port of the ssh comand to connect to the git project.

I am using gitlab on a private server on port `6022`. After serching a bit on the net I tried both: `ssh://git@gitlab.MyDomain:6022/'MyProject'.git`  and `git@gitlab.MyDomain:6022/'MyProject'.git` but none of those worked.

In the first I get the message: `"Could not read from remote reposatory"` and in the second: `"port 22: Bad file number fatal"` so It seems that ignore the port I manually put on the command and tries the default 22.

So How can I determine the port for the ssh ??

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue, for me I was trying to pass the username and the password via the URL.  After much trial and error the below worked for me, it will of course ask you for your password.

```
ssh://username@192.168.0.1:2222/home/username/repos/TestRepo
```